# How to use Android Developer Badge in SO profile

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, profile-page

How can we use Android Developer Badge ( Given on http://www.android.com/media/goodies.html ) in `About Me` section of SO profile ?  I tried but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to embed Flash objects in your profile or posts on Stack Overflow.